# Why Server.MapPath is adding extra directory in the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, rdlc, server.mappath

I am using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` function to locate a `StudentReport.rdlc` file which is under a `Class Library Project`.

**Solution Structure:**

[image]

I am calling below function which is in `Class Library Project` from a `Web API Project` named as `WebDemo`.

```
public class Reports
{
    public string GetReportPath()
    {

        string path1 = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        var path2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/StudentReport.rdlc");

        var path3 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/BL/ClassLib/StudentLib
                                                /Reports/StudentReport.rdlc");

        var path4 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/StudentLib/Reports
                                                /StudentReport.rdlc");

        string path5 = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/StudentLib/Reports
                                                /StudentReport.rdlc");

        return path5;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have tried all combinations of `Server.MapPath` but still it adds etc `WebDemo` directory in all the paths.

**Current Path:**

```
"C:\\Users\\tom\\source\\repos\\WebDemo\\WebDemo\\StudentLib\\Reports\\StudentReport.rdlc"
```

**Expected Path:**

```
"C:\\Users\\tom\\source\\repos\\WebDemo\\StudentLib\\Reports\\StudentReport.rdlc"
```

May I know why this is happening ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: That looks right to me... it looks like there's a *solution* folder `WebDemo`, and inside that there is a *project* folder also called `WebDemo`. Have you double-checked in explorer to see if it is right? i.e. does `C:\Users\tom\source\repos\WebDemo\WebDemo\StudentLib\Reports` exist and have your file in it?

Comment: note: libraries don't resolve from the library location - when you build, libraries are typically *copied* into the build output, with the application running purely from there; the fact that the library has a different path is irrelevant - that isn't where it comes from at runtime

Comment: `MapPath` is "I'll give you the extra sections you'd add to the URL for this web application's root, you tell me what physical path corresponds to that". But you're trying to supply a "URL" which doesn't refer to anything *within* the web application.

Comment: @MarcGravell , Yes you are right `C:\Users\tom\source\repos\WebDemo\WebDemo\StudentLib\Reports` exists.  So is there a way to get the absolute path  of the file inside `Class Library Project` without using `Server.MapPath` ? Or should I move the `StudentReport.rdlc` file Under `Web API Project` ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , So how do I get the path of `StudentReport.rdlc` file from a `Class Library Project` ?

Comment: @stom where it resides inside the class library project is frankly irrelevant; it isn't the class library that is running - it is the web application that runs, and the web application has a *copy* of what it needs from the class library. If you need to resolve the RDLC from the web app, the *easiest* way to do that is indeed to have it as content *in the web app*

Comment: If it "belongs" in the class library and should be available wherever the class library is used, you might be looking for embedded resources. But then, at the point of usage, it no longer *has* a physical path.

Comment: @MarcGravell ,Thanks,  Last question, Is it best practice to have `SSRS` `RDLC` files and `DataSets` Under `Web API project` ?

Comment: @stom that depends on where it notionally "belongs"; as Damien notes - you can use embedded resources, but the API for accessing those is quite different (it isn't a file, but you can still get a `Stream` for it)

Comment: @MarcGravell , Actually the requirement was to render `SSRS RDLC` report `PDF` as `bytes` to clients consuming the `API`, I am planning to move the `RDLC` files under `Web API project`. Thank you.